# Logrotate is not working in /tmp

Tags: debian, logrotate, tmp

I'm facing a strange problem with logrotate on my Debian 10 server.

All in one, logrotate (v3.20.1) is working and rotating fine... except for some files in /tmp that I want to "skrink" every day. Thoses logs are cvs files from collectd that I don't need to keep more than 24h.

My collectd configuration file is :

```
/var/log/collectd/collectd.log {
        weekly
        rotate 4
        create
        compress
        missingok
}

/tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/*/* {
        daily
        rotate 0
        copytruncate
        missingok
}
```

Here is a part of the logrotate log file :

```
rotating pattern: /var/log/collectd/collectd.log  weekly (4 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/collectd/collectd.log
  Now: 2022-12-09 00:00
  Last rotated at 2022-12-04 15:15
  log does not need rotating (log has been rotated at 2022-12-04 15:15, which is less than a week ago)

rotating pattern: /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/*/*  after 1 days (no old logs will be kept)
empty log files are rotated
considering log /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/*/*
```

The strange thing I can notice is in logrotate status file /var/lib/logrotate/status where the status date is stuck at 2022-12-1-0:0:0 for those files unlike the other entries.

```
# cat /var/lib/logrotate/status | sort
logrotate state -- version 2
"/tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/*/*" 2022-12-1-0:0:0
"/tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-idle" 2022-12-1-0:0:0
"/tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-interrupt" 2022-12-1-0:0:0
"/tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-nice" 2022-12-1-0:0:0
"/tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-softirq" 2022-12-1-0:0:0
...
"/tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/tcpconns-4772-remote/tcp_connections-SYN_SENT" 2022-12-1-0:0:0
"/tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/tcpconns-4772-remote/tcp_connections-TIME_WAIT" 2022-12-1-0:0:0
"/tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/uptime/uptime" 2022-12-1-0:0:0
...
"/var/log/borgbackup.log" 2022-12-4-15:15:18
"/var/log/btmp" 2022-12-1-0:0:1
"/var/log/chrony/*.log" 2022-1-13-18:0:0
"/var/log/clamav/clamav.log" 2022-12-4-15:15:18
"/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log" 2022-12-4-15:15:18
"/var/log/collectd/collectd.log" 2022-12-4-15:15:18
```

I have tried to run logrotate in debug mode and here is the result :

```
...
rotating pattern: /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/*/*  after 1 days (no old logs will be kept)
empty log files are rotated
considering log /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-idle
  Now: 2022-12-09 17:32
  Last rotated at 2022-12-01 00:00
  log needs rotating
...
rotating log /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-idle, log->rotateCount is 0
dateext suffix '-20221209'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-idle.1.bz2 to /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-idle.2.bz2 (rotatecount 1, logstart 1, i 1),
renaming /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-idle.0.bz2 to /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-idle.1.bz2 (rotatecount 1, logstart 1, i 0),
log /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-idle.2.bz2 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
skip copying /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-idle to /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-idle.1
truncating /tmp/collectd/csv/localhost/cpu-0/cpu-idle
compressing log with: /bin/lbzip2
...
```

But the file is not rotated at midnight every day and keep growing :(

Is it possible to rotate a file in /tmp ? It seems that it's possible but what could be the problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check `/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service` config and make sure  `PrivateTmp` option is set to `false`.

Do not forget `systemctl daemon-reload`

I just found out for myself that Logrotate is handled not by Cron but  Systemd timer. Discovery of the year!

Comment: Hi,

I've just noticed that a few days ago. I'm going to try your setting today as it is set to true at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my systemd conf file for logrotate service.

```
# cat logrotate.service
[Unit]
Description=Rotate log files
Documentation=man:logrotate(8) man:logrotate.conf(5)
ConditionACPower=true

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate -v --log=/var/log/logrotate/logrotate.log /etc/logrotate.conf

# performance options
Nice=19
IOSchedulingClass=best-effort
IOSchedulingPriority=7

# hardening options
#  details: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html
#  no ProtectHome for userdir logs
#  no PrivateNetwork for mail deliviery
#  no ProtectKernelTunables for working SELinux with systemd older than 235
#  no MemoryDenyWriteExecute for gzip on i686
PrivateDevices=true
PrivateTmp=false
ProtectControlGroups=true
ProtectKernelModules=true
ProtectSystem=full
RestrictRealtime=true
```